# How do I call forEach in an addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with names and grades of some students. I have to sort them out in descending order which I have, using  forEach method, however I can't figure out how to call it in an addEventListener so that when I press a button it displays the name and the grades of the students in my browser. In the HTML document I only have one empty paragraph with an id of "#demo" and a button with an id of "#showStudents" which is supposed to display the names and grades in the empty paragraph when clicked. Down below I have attached the code:

```
const studentsOrder = document.getElementById("demo");
const showStudents = document.getElementById("showStudents");

const students = [
  {
    name: "Michael",
    grade: 9,
  },

  {
    name: "Tom",
    grade: 6,
  },

  {
    name: "Lisa",
    grade: 8,
  },

  {
    name: "Ron",
    grade: 5,
  },

  {
    name: "Daniel",
    grade: 3,
  },

  {
    name: "John",
    grade: 2,
  },

  {
    name: "Louise",
    grade: 7,
  },
];

students.sort((a, b) => b.grade - a.grade);

students.forEach((e) => {
  console.log(`${e.name} ${e.grade}`);
});
```

Comment: Put the code in an event listener, and make it update the DOM with the result instead of using `console.log()`. Which part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: Where's the HTML and the code trying to modify it? Right now it just looks like you're asking someone to write it for you. We'd rather teach you what's wrong with what you've tried.

Comment: @Barmar, that is the part I'm having trouble with: I can't figure out how to put the code in an event listener instead of using console.log().

Comment: @Teodor-MihaiAvasilcai Your existing code is not even attempting to modify the DOM or set the even listener.  `studentsOrder.addEventListener('click', ()=> students.forEach((e) => {  showStudents.innerHTML += \`${e.name} ${e.grade} <br />\`);
});` This is very rough... just to get you started

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm not trying to get people to write it for me but all I have in the HTML code is a button and an empty paragraph: <body>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button id="showStudents">Show Students</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: @JuanMendes Thank you. I'm sorry if it looked like I was trying to get people to write it for me. I put the JavaScript code in my question but the only thing I was struggling with was replacing that console.log() in the forEach method with a way to display it in the Broswer. Thank you so much again, now I understand what I was doing wrong

Comment: Do you know how to add event listeners in general? If you do, what's different about this?

Comment: @Teodor-MihaiAvasilcai have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments you'll have to attach the listener to the button `#showStudents` and show them in the `#demo`

```js
const studentsOrder = document.getElementById("demo");
const showStudents = document.getElementById("showStudents");

const students = [{
    name: "Michael",
    grade: 9,
  },

  {
    name: "Tom",
    grade: 6,
  },

  {
    name: "Lisa",
    grade: 8,
  },

  {
    name: "Ron",
    grade: 5,
  },

  {
    name: "Daniel",
    grade: 3,
  },

  {
    name: "John",
    grade: 2,
  },

  {
    name: "Louise",
    grade: 7,
  },
];

students.sort((a, b) => b.grade - a.grade);
showStudents.addEventListener('click', () => {
  studentsOrder.innerHTML = ''
  students.forEach(e => studentsOrder.innerHTML += `${e.name} ${e.grade} <br />`);
})
```

```html
<button id="showStudents">Show Students</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

---

A one liner solution could be using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method, something like this:

```js
const studentsOrder = document.getElementById("demo");
const showStudents = document.getElementById("showStudents");

const students = [{
    name: "Michael",
    grade: 9,
  },

  {
    name: "Tom",
    grade: 6,
  },

  {
    name: "Lisa",
    grade: 8,
  },

  {
    name: "Ron",
    grade: 5,
  },

  {
    name: "Daniel",
    grade: 3,
  },

  {
    name: "John",
    grade: 2,
  },

  {
    name: "Louise",
    grade: 7,
  },
];

students.sort((a, b) => b.grade - a.grade);
showStudents.addEventListener('click', () => studentsOrder.innerHTML = students.reduce((accumulator, student) => `${accumulator} <br /> ${student.name} ${student.grade}`, ''))
```

```html
<button id="showStudents">Show Students</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Might want to empty the DIV first, so it doesn't duplicate each time.

Comment: No need to sort the array every time you click

Comment: @JuanMendes true that, fixed

Comment: Since you took on the answer, the last suggestion is to avoid recreating the DOM for every iteration ( set the HTML in a single shot) :p and turn it into a one liner. `studentsOrder.innerHTML = students.reduce((str, student) => \`${str} <br /> ${student.name} ${student.grade}\`, '')`

Comment: Yeah that would be a good "upgrade" per say ;) I'll add it to my answer